# React native download base64 image list as a single PDF file

Tags: android, ios, react-native, pdf, download

I want to download list of base64 images as single pdf file in to my device.I have implemented following for that, issue is download is working correctly but can't open the downloaded file getting **"Cannot display PDF(file_name.pdf is of invalid format)"**

Code:

```
const externalStorageDirectory =
        Platform.OS === 'android'
          ? RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath
          : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;

const imageArray = downloadImages.map(item => item.image);

const downloadPdf = async () => {
        try {
          const pdfContent = imageArray
            .map(base64Image => `<img src=${base64Image} />`)
            .join('');
          const downloadPath = externalStorageDirectory + '/downloaded.pdf';
          await RNFS.writeFile(downloadPath, pdfContent);
          console.log('PDF downloaded successfully:', downloadPath);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error downloading PDF:', error);
        }
 };

 downloadPdf();
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: I dont see you downloading anything.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are attempting to produce a PDF file with base64-encoded images. However, it's possible that the method you're using to accomplish this—directly embedding  tags in the PDF file—is incorrect. The format and structure of PDF files are unique, thus you should utilise a library that can create PDF files.

To convert HTML content—including images—into a PDF file, I suggest utilising a library like react-native-html-to-pdf.

Here's an example of how to change your code:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf';

const externalStorageDirectory =
  Platform.OS === 'android'
    ? RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath
    : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;

const imageArray = downloadImages.map(item => item.image);

const downloadPdf = async () => {
  try {
    const imgTags = imageArray.map(
      base64Image => `<img src="${base64Image}" style="max-width:100%;" />`
    );

    const htmlContent = `<html><body>${imgTags.join('')}</body></html>`;

    const options = {
      html: htmlContent,
      fileName: 'downloaded',
      directory: externalStorageDirectory,
    };

    const pdfFile = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
    console.log('PDF downloaded successfully:', pdfFile.filePath);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error downloading PDF:', error);
  }
};

downloadPdf();
```

Comment: Thank you, I implemented the soultion same way.

Comment: it's my pleasure that my provided answer works for you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy